# jUDDI Installation and configuration

Tags: web-services, wsdl, tomcat7, uddi, juddi

I have installed the basic jUDDI Server in my machine. I am able to Register the Service and able to read my Service info as a new user. I want to restrict the users who wants to look up my services. I want only my clients to access these information. I want to authenticate them so only my clients can view the business, service, tModel, Binding Template information. How can I achieve this? Can any body help me get through this?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Break down your problem into smaller pieces, and attempt them one at a time, then post with any specific questions you have about why something doesn't work as you expected. After reading the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on the setting the requires authentication for the inquiry API. You can find it in the juddiv3.xml config file for the server. Here's the xpath to get you there.

`config/juddi/auth/Inquiry=true`

Future readers, the documentation is located here for the current release (as of this time of this post)
https://juddi.apache.org/docs/3.3/juddi-guide/html/ch04.html#_administering_users_and_access_control

but the website https://juddi.apache.org/docs.html will get you to whatever is current. The docs (that website) is also available as part of the distribution and (i think) maven artifacts

Comment: I have enabled the Inquiry to true. But still I am able to access the service as a new user. Can you please tell me how to enable xml file based authentication? XMLDocAuthenticator. I have followed the jUDDI docs but I failed.

Comment: As mentioned in the docs section 4.2.2.5 https://juddi.apache.org/docs/3.3/juddi-guide/html/ch04.html#_administering_users_and_access_control , the default authenticator does no password validation. The instructions are pretty clear. Make an xml file, copy and paste the example, edit juddiv3.xml to point to the xml file. what's the problem?

Comment: I am trainee and new to this jUDDI terminology. I thought that the juddi-users.xml file is predefined. Any ways thanks for your help.